# Stick/Hinge header to the browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created sticky header which is working fine but when it is sticking to the top there is some jerk in menu. Unable to figure out why.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.filter-header, .left-panel').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('.filter-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                } else {
                        $('.filter-header').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                }
        });
});
```

**[FIDDLE Updated](http://jsbin.com/iseXIqEf/14/)**

Comment: position fixed might be the issue because your UL is not taking parent div as relative after scrolling.

Comment: the moment the fixed position is assigned to .filter-header on user scroll, the width: 100% property value that the said element has been assigned will take reference to the viewport rather than it's immediate parent. it is likely in the discrepancy of a different width value that is causing the list items to move about. you might want to try setting a static width if the scope permits.

Answer (score 1):

.top is not a jquery function and an error is thrown.

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('.filter-header, .left-panel').offset().top;
```

Replace with:

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('.filter-header, .left-panel').offset();
```

An object is returned and can be accessed like so:

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop.top) {
```

However this can be done with css.

jquery offset(): http://api.jquery.com/offset/ some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need for this to be achieved with javascript? Why not use CSS?

Something like this

Example - http://jsbin.com/iseXIqEf/11/edit

CSS

```
#header { position: fixed; width: 100%; background: #CCC; top:0; }
```

Comment: I have header above the sticky menu so it should stick to top only when users scroll up. PLease check my updated demo

Answer (score 0):

```
    .filter-header {
/*try adding left and right positions*/
       left: 40px;
       right: 40px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /*width: 100%;*/
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by adding width to fixed div when it is scrolled up. And now it is not stretching to full width when scroll up.

```
//Primary filter and left panel hing
         // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.filter-header, .left-panel').offset().top;

       $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('.filter-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', width: '97%'});
                } else {
                        $('.filter-header').css({position: 'static', top: '0px', width: '100%'});
                }
        });
```